# Passing variable to Expect and Spawn

Tags: bash, variables, scp, spawn

I'm writing a script that will **scp** a tar file from my local server to a remote host. Since the script generates the file through a pre-requisite process, the name is generated dynamically. My script needs to take the name of the file and pass it to scp for transfer.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn scp test.$(date +%y%m%d_%H%M).tar user@IP-ADDRESS:/destination/folder
set pass "password"
expect "password: "
send -- "$pass\r"
expect eof
```

I've tried setting the filename as a variable but keep seeing the same error:

> can't read "(date +%y%m%d_%H%M)": no such variable
>       while executing "spawn scp test.$(date +%y%m%d_%H%M).tar user@IP-ADDRESS:/destination/folder"

Comment: Is public-key authentication an option? It's much simpler than using `expect` (and more secure than hardcoding a password in a script).

Comment: The problem is that you aren't writing a shell script; you are writing a Tcl script that executes a shell command. I don't recall the correct syntax for command substitution in Tcl (hence this comment, rather than an answer).

Comment: Unfortunately, Jenkins is using this script to build locally due to a node version dependancy and eventually pushing the .tar file to destination. Thought of public key auth initially but security restrictions at work.

Comment: Maybe I really don't understand how Jenkins works, if hardcoding the password in a script is the "secure" option.

Comment: You can use credentials service in Jenkins and create a reference to those credentials in your Jenkinsfile which will remove plain text passwords in your script and build logs.

Comment: I would do that, then. Treat `expect` as an absolute last resort for programs that provide no other non-interactive options.

Answer (score 0):

`$(date +%y%m%d_%H%M)` is not a Tcl command. If you use *expect*, you have to learn Tcl. To get a formatted date in Tcl, use the [clock](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/clock.htm) command. Also, interpolation of the result from a command in Tcl is not done by `$(....)`, but by `[....]`. You can find examples for this construct [here](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl5.html).

Answer (score 0):

Decided to go another route since the team was able to provision a new Artifactory repo for this binary and alike. However, to the advice provided here I was able to make a few discoveries which I used to fix my issues:

**I also had a password with $ symbol and that also caused a world of issues.**

```
#!/bin/bash

TEST=$(date +%y%m%d_%H%M)
/usr/bin/expect <<eof

set password {pas\$word}
spawn scp "$TEST" user@IP-ADDRESS:/destination/folder
expect "*password:"
send "$pasword\r"
expect eof
```